# Huge inconsistency in disk space measurement, missing 50% of the disk

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space

I own a MacBook Pro 13 Retina, OSX reports disk usage as 450Gb, but utilities such as DiskInventoryX tells a different story reporting 226Gb as used disk space:

[image: Disk space screenshots]

How can I convince OSX to give me back my disk space?
Given that DiskInventoryX (and other I tested) cannot find where these 411Gb marked as "Other" are what can I do to identify the issue?

Output of `df -h`

```
Device Block Size: 512 Bytes  

/dev/disk1 465Gi 421Gi 43Gi 91%  110450433 11387165 91%  
devfs      184Ki 184Ki 0Bi  100% 638       0        100%
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Large difference in reported free disk space](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70983/large-difference-in-reported-free-disk-space)

Comment: the differences I see are much bigger than the size of the backup, that is correctly reported up there. Running "sudo tmutil disablelocal" has no effects at all, even after a cold boot.
Finder reports the same wrong size as "About this Mac"

Comment: You might be interested in this recent [post on OS X daily](http://osxdaily.com/2015/01/15/other-storage-space-mac-os-x/).

Comment: Did you do a disk repair?

Comment: yes, no effects

Comment: Administrators, please note this **is not** a duplicate of [Large difference in reported free disk space](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70983/large-difference-in-reported-free-disk-space). The root cause is not Time Machine related. Instead it appears to be `MobileBackups.trash` related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be seeing the difference between used **bytes** versus [used **blocks**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/78802/what-are-the-sector-sizes-on-mac-os-x) on the disk.

If a tool iterates over the files on your disk and totals the file sizes in bytes, the total value will not match the used disk space.

Try using other disk tools to determine the remaining disk space. The `df` tool should provide some insight `df -h`.

Consider using a tool like [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net) to view the contents of your drive; it appears better maintained than [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com). Be aware that these tools show file size and not blocks used.

[image]

Comment: do you think is it possible that the difference causes such a huge difference in disk space report? (200Gb)

Comment: In extreme cases it is possible. What does `df` say? How big is your drive's block size?

Comment: Device Block Size: 512 Bytes

/dev/disk1 465Gi  421Gi   43Gi    91% 110450433 11387165   91%  


devfs      184Ki  184Ki    0Bi   100%       638        0  100%

Comment: Please could you add this output to your question and format it as a code block to retain the spacing.

Comment: Running GrandPerspective from the Terminal / sudo it seems that I have found the root cause of the issue there is a huge file (a Parallels VM) here: /.MobileBackups.trash/Computer/2013-12-11-194848/Volume/Users/mauro/Documents/Windows 8.1.pvm how can I remove it?

Comment: Good to hear you found the cause. Please can you start a new question for finding out how to empty `MobileBackups.trash`; you will attract better answers and help others suffering the same problem.

Comment: Done here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168180/how-to-empty-mobilebackups-trash-content

Answer (score 0):

After deleting a user account of about 800GB on a new Max OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite system with a 1TB SSD, I was left with only 400GB of free space instead of the expected 900GB.

A whole disk scan of the system by GrandPerspective reported that the scanned files (all of "/" ) were only about 35 GB in size, and that "Miscellaneous used space" was a few hundred GB, which should have been deleted/freed when I killed off the unwanted user account.

I ran Disk Utililty.app to "Erase Free Space" and it churned away creating temporary files to write to the "unused space". While that was running, GrandPerspective reported smaller "Miscellaneous used space" and the Finder reported around 700 GB of free space (up from just a few hundred). Then it jumped to larger "misc used" and smaller "free". Then it reported "running out of room on boot drive!" then it failed with a "cannot create temp file" error, but after I quit Disk Utility.app the finder reported 963GB free space, as did Disk Utility.app as did GrandPerspectives.

So the long and sort of it is that running "Erase Free Space" via Disk Utility.app freed up that free space.